# inheritance of a variable from source overriding my current variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

index.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
source "global.sh"
echo "${CODE_DIR}/SOMETHING"
```

global.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
APP_DIR="/app001/Documents/files/" 
CODE_DIR="${APP_DIR}/code"
```

When I run index.sh:

Expected output: `/app001/Documents/files/code/SOMETHING`

output: `/SOMETHINGcuments/files//code`

Why? and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: About the slashes you have `...files/` and `${APP_DIR}/`, so, two slashes together.

Comment: About the `SOMETHINGcuments` I copy/paste your code and got the expected result. There must be a typo somewhere

Comment: I'm pretty sure at least one of your files has DOS/Windows line endings -- see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings).

Comment: With your files as shown in the question on my Ubuntu 19.04 I get an error message `./index.sh: 2: ./index.sh: source: not found` followed by `/SOMETHING` because `source` is not valid POSIX shell syntax. After changing `index.sh` to `#!/bin/bash` I get `/app001/Documents/files//code/SOMETHING`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because your `global.sh` has DOS file format, which encodes end of lines as a carriage return followed by a newline character.

Linux/Unix will only consider the newline character to be a newline, so the carriage return will become part of the contents of the variable `${CODE_DIR}`.

When you echo a carriage return character, the cursor goes back to the beginning of the line. That's what's happening in this case, first it's printing `/app001/Documents/files//code` from `${CODE_DIR}`, then the carriage return at the end of that variable will move the cursor back to the beginning of the line, and then the `/SOMETHING` part will overwrite the start of the string.

You can visualize that by piping the output through `cat -v` which will show all characters, it will show the carriage return as `^M`:

```
$ ./index.sh | cat -v
/app001/Documents/files//code^M/SOMETHING
```

In order to fix it, convert the newlines on `global.sh` to Unix format, which you can do using the `dos2unix` tool, if available on your machine.

```
$ dos2unix global.sh
```

Or open the file in Vim and convert it there:

```
$ vim global.sh
:set ff=dos
:wq
```

You might want to check your other files (such as `index.sh`) for DOS line endings. You might also want to check why `global.sh` ended up with DOS file endings and fix that. If you're using a text editor to create these files, check that the text editor is properly configured to always use Unix line endings.